# Can GPU be used in numerical calculations (Complex matrix multiplication) on Android Environmement?

Tags: java, android, gpu, fpu, kalman-filter

I am implementing  Kalman filter algorithm in Android. The code has some complex matrix multiplication operations. The matrix elements are of type float. My question is

1) how are floating point handled in Android??

2) Can GPU be used in complex matrix (elements of type float) calculations or any kind of numerical calculations?

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you looked into Renderscript? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html

Answer (score 2):

android.opengl.Matrix library took care of this for you

renderscript seems to be a more user controllable solution.

Comment: android.opengl.Matrix library is used for computer graphics. I am looking for library that does numerical calculations using GPU in Android environment. A library that helps increase the performance of program which deals with large complex matrix calculations.

Comment: ^^ What the hell do you think computer graphics are, if not libraries that do numerical calculations using the GPU, helping to increase the performance of a program which deals with large complex matrix calculations?

I need an algorithm that puts a series of numbers into a set order. 
-- "Sorting algorithms are over here. "
-- No. Those are for lists. I have a series of numbers.